# Gerix Wifi Cracker and Aircrack-ng in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

I am have install [Aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/index.html) from its official site. Compiling its source and installing.

And [Gerix](https://github.com/TigerSecurity/gerix-wifi-cracker) also from official site Source.

I am using AR9285 with ath9k drivers included default with Ubuntu 12.04

But on Performing injection test its says "mon  is on channel -1" and i am unable to perform injection.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4BrK.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Aircrack-ng homepage you might have missed:

> #### Channel -1 issues
>
> If you are receiving an error message talking about channel -1, you either have to patch your driver like explained in the [wiki](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless) or get the latest version of Aircrack-ng from our subversion repository and use the option --ignore-negative-one. You can find an installation guide also in the [wiki](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#latest_svn_development_sources).

If you've already compiled this from SVN, try adding the `--ignore-negative-one` argument to your injection command.

To have Gerix do that for you, you're going to need to open the script and look for where it calls `aireplay` (et al).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your driver is compatible.

And have a look in the aircrack-ng wiki for the channel-1 issue

http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless

Comment: Thanks, my Device is supported out of Box. I have checked then once again.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was commissioned to teach someone how to crack wifi, the pc used to perform the wireless audit was Ubuntu 12.04.  I had this same issue but **was able to overcome the problem by updating the kernel from 3.2 to 3.6.** This fixed the problem.  I tried a patch and that was unsuccessful.  Best of luck, should solve your issues.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you explain (or link to information about) how to upgrade the kernel? (The best place for this would be in your answer itself--you can edit it to add this.)